# Css não fica no HTML

Tags: html, html5

Como faço pra esse HTML carregar com o CSS em outro dispositivo. No meu pc ele carrega o css normal, mas quando mando uma amiga abrir pra mim, mando pra ela somente o arquivo HTML e só aparece o HTML mesmo. Como faço pra carregar o css junto???

```
<head> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="C:\Users\PhodZ\Documents\Codes\Tests/css.css">

</head>
<form action="" method="POST"></form>

<h1 id="test">

</h1>
<div id="testb">

</div>
<div id="teste">
    <label for="testea" id="testea">Nome</label>
    <input type="text" id="aaa" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estou supondo que não consiga enviar para ela os 2 arquivos (HTML e CSS), correto?!

Estão temos 3 opções!

1) Colocar o conteúdo do arquivo CSS na tag  dentro da

Desta maneira somente o arquivo HTML vai ser suficiente.

```
<head>
  <style> SEU CONTEUDO DO ARQUIVO CSS </style>
</head>
```

2) Colocar o CSS em um servidor WEB ou em nuvem de modo público (Ex.: Google Cloud Storage) e no *href* do link do CSS, colcoar a URL do CSS. Neste caso, ela precisa ter **conexão de internet** para o arquivo ser carregado!

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://meuservidor/meuarquivocss.css">
```

3) Utilize um editor online, como https://jsfiddle.net/, e compartilhe com ela.

Espero que ajude!

Comment: CARA EU TE AMO DE UMA MANEIRA!!!! OBRIGADO!!!!!!

Comment: mas pera, tem um servidor gratuito?

Comment: O Cloud Storage da Google é gratuito para testar! https://cloud.google.com/storage

Answer (score -1):

Fala Pedro, bem vindo ao [pt.stackOverFlow](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/)!

Quando nos referenciamos à uma estilização *CSS* do tipo externo (da maneira que você está usando), o atributo `href` indica o caminho de qual o arquivo *CSS* deve ser lido e interpretado.

Quando você passa apenas o arquivo `.html` para a sua amiga, ao executá-lo na máquina dela, na construção do HTML, o interpretador vai ler este `<link>` e procurar pelo arquivo no seguinte diretório `C:\Users\PhodZ\Documents\Codes\Tests/css.css`, porém não vai ser encontrado. Por isso o arquivo apenas interpreta o código HTML.

Comment: Lembrando que, caso você envie o arquivo **css**, ele deve estar nesse mesmo diretório: **C:\Users\PhodZ\Document...**

Comment: okkk, e como eu faço pra resolver isso?

Comment: fazendo com que o css continue do tipo externo e carregue